# continuous/smooth Fourier transform

Tags: lp-spaces, fourier-transform, schwartz-space

Let $f$ be a function with

a) $f\in L^1(\mathbb R^d)$ 
b) $f\in \mathcal S(\mathbb R^d)$ (The Schwartz-space)
c) $f\in L^2(\mathbb R^d)$
and given the following statements:\

(i) $f$ continuous $\Rightarrow \hat{f}$ continuous
(ii) $f$ smooth $\Rightarrow \hat{f}$ smooth.\

I know (i) and (ii) are false for c) because the Fourier transform of $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is not continuous.
(i) and (ii) are correct because the Fourier transform of a Schwartz function is a Schwartz function and per definition a Schwartz function is smooth.
But what about a)?

Comment: If $f$ is in the Schwarz space then $f$ and $\hat f$ are both smooth, That doesn't say that $f$ smooth _implies_ $\hat f$ smooth...

Comment: @David: True $\Rightarrow$ True is a true statement

Comment: @PhoemueX I want to just say "True". Alas I also want to point out that I didn't actually deny that. I said something about "implies", in an informal context - the informal meaning is not exactly $\implies$, quite.

Answer (score 3):

As the fourier transform maps $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ to a continuous function, (i) is true there too.

(ii) shouldn't be true.
Consider $x \mapsto \left(\frac{sin(x)}{x}\right)^2$ and its fourier transform.